# Powershell dynamic path when create folder

Tags: powershell

I want to create a folder, but I don't know how use a variable for define the path.

As is:

```
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "C:\Users\tizio.caio\Desktop\BACKUP_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd'))"
```

I want to replace `C:\Users\tizio.caio\Desktop\` with a variable in order to make future reworks easier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want the current users desktop, you can use the [`Environment.GetFolderPath()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) to retrieve the path, then use the [`Join-Path` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) to combine it with the directory name:

```
$DesktopPath = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)
$DirectoryName = "BACKUP_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd'))"
$DirectoryPath = Join-Path $DesktopPath $DirectoryName
```

You could pack it into a function that takes a `-Path` parameter if you want to be able to override it:

```
function New-BackupDirectory
{
    param(
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        $Path = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)
    )

    $DirectoryName = "BACKUP_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd'))"
    $DirectoryPath = Join-Path $Path $DirectoryName

    mkdir $DirectoryPath
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, no, the user desktop is not the final location.. I tried something like your but alway failed when create the string:        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "C:\Users\tizio.caio\Desktop\BACKUP_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd'))"

Comment: What do you mean "failed"? Please be more specific about what you want to achieve and how what you're attempting it's failing

Comment: I mean the folder not be created.. 
I tried to set a variable and use it in the path, but nothing.

Comment: New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "$Location\Datasources\BACKUP_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd'))"

now i have:
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "C:\Users\tizio.caio\Desktop\Datasources\BACKUP_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd'))"

Answer (score 0):

I would split the directory and filename, and use the [environment variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx) `USERPROFILE`

```
$var    = $env:USERPROFILE + "\Desktop\"
$backup = "BACKUP_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd'))"

New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "$var$backup"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending how simple you want to go:

```
$folderpath = "C:\Users\tizio.caio\Desktop"
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "$folderpath\BACKUP_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd'))"
```

Or you can combine multiple variables:

```
$folderpath = "C:\Users\tizio.caio\Desktop"
$backuppath = "$folderpath\BACKUP_$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd'))"
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $backuppath
```

Comment: Hi James, i did exactly your first solution , but doesnt work.. :(

Comment: @Alex Be specific, `doesn't work` is a childish reply. **what** and how doesn't work. It might fail if you have no rights on `"C:\Users\tizio.caio\Desktop"`  Try `$folderpath = "$($Env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop"`

Comment: I wrote "doesnt work" because I dont know why the folder not be created..
I have the rights to create folder, but I'll not use userprofile because the final location will be on a shared folder in a server machine..

Comment: Folder didnt create. The script runs but customizing the path with a variable the folder didnt create. Using entire path works.

Comment: @JamesC.I have tried your method but I keep getting the path's format is not supported.

Comment: @Waqas Ask a question and include your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask